# How to Write IF ELSE Statements inside RETURN QUERY EXECUTE in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I'm getting syntax error while writing `IF ELSE` statements inside `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` in PostgreSQL 11.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tds_master.a_report(
    i_entity_id integer,
    i_client_id integer,
    i_branch_id integer,
    i_name text,
    i_finyear integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(employee_name character varying(100), pan character varying(10), optfor115bac character varying(1), 
                  taxable_income numeric, income_tax numeric, credit_us_87a numeric, surcharge numeric, education_cess numeric) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
    
   'if i_name != '' then   
     select
       ed.name as employee_name,
       ed.pan,
       sd.opting_for_us115bac,
       sd.total_taxable_income,
       sd.income_tax_on_total_income,
       sd.rebate_us87a,
       sd.surcharge,
       sd.education_cess
    from tds' || i_finyear || '.saldet sd
       inner join tds' || i_finyear || '.employee_deductee ed on ed.ed_id = sd.employee_id
       where sd.entity_id = $1 and sd.client_id = $2 and sd.branch_id = $3 and upper(ed.name)=upper(i_name);
       
    else
      
    select 
       ed.name as employee_name,
       ed.pan,
       sd.opting_for_us115bac,
       sd.total_taxable_income,
       sd.income_tax_on_total_income,
       sd.rebate_us87a,
       sd.surcharge,
       sd.education_cess
    from tds' || i_finyear || '.saldet sd
       inner join tds' || i_finyear || '.employee_deductee ed on ed.ed_id = sd.employee_id
       where sd.entity_id = $1 and sd.client_id = $2 and sd.branch_id = $3'
  
    USING i_entity_id, i_client_id, i_branch_id;
    
END;
$BODY$;
```

CALL Function:

```
select * 
from tds_master.a_report(1547,6393,0,'MADAKE VINOD BABURAO',2021);
```

OUTPUT:

[image: image with error message]

Comment: `EXECUTE` executes **SQL** - and there is no `IF` in SQL. You need to use an `IF` inside PL/pgSQL and run different queries. `if (...) then execute '...' else execute '...' end if;`

Comment: Or just `and (i_name =''  OR upper(ed.name)=upper(i_name))` and omit the else part.

Comment: `from tds' || i_finyear || '.saldet sd` <<-- you cannot use integers in string concatenation. Also: use the format() function to avoid quoting errors.

Comment: I find **CASE** easier to get the syntax right than **IF**

Comment: Please post text as text. Never as image.

Comment: Follow the docs [IF-THEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) *43.6.4.1. IF-THEN*. Hint this : `'if i_name ...` is the first problem, there should be no leading `'`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ..ok.. let me check.. thanks.

Comment: @wildplasser we can use integers in string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up about PL/pgSQL syntax as hinted in the comments.

However, you can just merge your query variants and use a plain `OR` for the possibly empty / null input parameter `i_name`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tds_master.a_report(
    i_entity_id integer,
    i_client_id integer,
    i_branch_id integer,
    i_name text,
    i_finyear integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(employee_name varchar(100), pan varchar(10), optfor115bac varchar(1)
              , taxable_income numeric, income_tax numeric, credit_us_87a numeric
              , surcharge numeric, education_cess numeric) 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
   $q$
   SELECT ed.name -- AS employee_name
        , ed.pan
        , sd.opting_for_us115bac
        , sd.total_taxable_income
        , sd.income_tax_on_total_income
        , sd.rebate_us87a
        , sd.surcharge
        , sd.education_cess
   FROM   %1$I.saldet sd
   JOIN   %1$I.employee_deductee ed ON ed.ed_id = sd.employee_id
   WHERE  sd.entity_id = $1
   AND    sd.client_id = $2
   AND    sd.branch_id = $3       
   AND   (i_name = '' OR  i_name IS NULL OR upper(ed.name) = upper(i_name))  -- !
   $q$, 'tds' || i_finyear::text)
   USING i_entity_id, i_client_id, i_branch_id;
END
$func$;
```

Much simpler. Same performance.

I use `format()`, which is the clean approach. Granted, while you only concatenate an integer value, plain concatenation is reasonably safe.

Comment: sorry for the late reply,, Thanks a lot it's perfectly works for me